# Colour Scale formatting using VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have Excel sheet and I need to use VBA to make conditional formatting "color scale "red-yellow-green" for the range `k5:o5` for the range form `k2:o2` if column J contains USD then need to offset one cell and apply the same formatting till the end of the sheet in case J contains USD.

I tried many codes but it's not working and need support. I got the below code from chat GPT but it's not working.

```vb
Sub ApplyColorScale()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim lastRow As Long
    Dim rng As Range
    
    ' Set the worksheet object
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1") ' Replace "Sheet1" with your sheet name
    
    ' Find the last row in column J
    lastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "J").End(xlUp).Row
    
    ' Set the range for conditional formatting
    Set rng = ws.Range("K5:O5")
    
    ' Apply conditional formatting to each row where column J contains "USD"
    For Each cell In ws.Range("J2:J" & lastRow)
        If cell.Value = "USD" Then
            rng.Offset(cell.Row - 2).FormatConditions.AddColorScale ColorScaleType:=3
            rng.Offset(cell.Row - 2).FormatConditions(rng.Offset(cell.Row - 2)).ColorScaleCriteria(1).Type = xlConditionValueLowestValue
            rng.Offset(cell.Row - 2).FormatConditions(rng.Offset(cell.Row - 2)).ColorScaleCriteria(1).FormatColor.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
            rng.Offset(cell.Row - 2).FormatConditions(rng.Offset(cell.Row - 2)).ColorScaleCriteria(2).Type = xlConditionValuePercentile
            rng.Offset(cell.Row - 2).FormatConditions(rng.Offset(cell.Row - 2)).ColorScaleCriteria(2).Value = 50
            rng.Offset(cell.Row - 2).FormatConditions(rng.Offset(cell.Row - 2)).ColorScaleCriteria(3).Type = xlConditionValueHighestValue
            rng.Offset(cell.Row - 2).FormatConditions(rng.Offset(cell.Row - 2)).ColorScaleCriteria(3).FormatColor.Color = RGB(0, 255, 0)
        End If
    Next cell
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

You are almost there,  just add a few more lines of code.
Let's clear previous format conditions before adding a new one. then simplify the conditional formatting part.

```
Sub ApplyColorScale()

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim lastRow As Long
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim fc As ColorScale

    ' Set the worksheet object
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1") ' Replace "Sheet1" with your sheet name

    ' Find the last row in column J
    lastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "J").End(xlUp).Row

    ' Loop through  J to check for "USD"
    For Each cell In ws.Range("J2:J" & lastRow)
        If cell.Value = "USD" Then
            ' Set the range for conditional formatting
            Set rng = cell.Offset(0, 1).Resize(1, 5) ' It will cover K to O for that row
            
            ' Delete any existing color scales
            rng.FormatConditions.Delete
            
            ' Add new color scale
            Set fc = rng.FormatConditions.AddColorScale(ColorScaleType:=3)
            
            fc.ColorScaleCriteria(1).Type = xlConditionValueLowestValue
            fc.ColorScaleCriteria(1).FormatColor.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
            fc.ColorScaleCriteria(2).Type = xlConditionValuePercentile
            fc.ColorScaleCriteria(2).Value = 50
            fc.ColorScaleCriteria(2).FormatColor.Color = RGB(255, 255, 0)
            fc.ColorScaleCriteria(3).Type = xlConditionValueHighestValue
            fc.ColorScaleCriteria(3).FormatColor.Color = RGB(0, 255, 0)
        End If
    Next cell

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you Mr vbakin for this great assist  but i need one small update

Comment: i need the lower value to be green hight value  red and mid vaue yellow

Comment: You can change color by update values at the lines below. Like below.

fc.ColorScaleCriteria(1).FormatColor.Color = RGB(0, 255, 0) ' Green for the lowest value

fc.ColorScaleCriteria(2).FormatColor.Color = RGB(255, 255, 0) ' Yellow for the middle value

fc.ColorScaleCriteria(3).FormatColor.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0) ' Red for the highest value